# What does assignment operator means in return statements, like return t =...?

Tags: c++, enums, return

I have question: What does it mean to return an assignment expression like in my code example? I have an `enum`, and I have overridden the `++:operator`. So it is possible to switch between lights in my short example - but there is a part in the code I dont understand. The code compiles and work fine.

Code:

```
enum Traficlight
{green, yellow, red };

Traficlight& operator++(Traficlight& t)
{
    switch (t)
    {
    case green: return t = Traficlight::yellow; //Here <--
    case yellow: return t = Traficlight::red; //Here <--
    case red: return t = Traficlight::green; //Here <--
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{


    Traficlight Trafic = Traficlight::green;
    Trafic++;

    if (Trafic == Traficlight::yellow)
    {
        cout << "Light is Yellow" << endl;
    }

    string in;

    cin >> in;

}
```

What does the `return t = Traficlight::yellow` mean, why can't I just `return Traficlight::yellow`?

Comment: For more info on the return value of the assignment operator, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697643/low-level-details-of-c-c-assignment-operator-implementation-what-does-it-retu

Comment: It's the same as `t = x; return x;`.

Comment: This code does not compile: you define preincrement `operator++` but use postincrement `operator++`.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, it's good programming practice to mimic the effects of built-in `operator++`, which in the prefix version both modifies the parameter and returns its value.

Comment: @aschepler just noticed that now, my comment is deleted.

Comment: @aschepler compiles for me

Comment: You're sure you don't also have a `TraficLight operator++(TraficLight&, int);` you didn't copy?

Comment: No i have Traficlight& operator++(Traficlight& t) and it works fine, i wrote it my self but the example was from a book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the return instructions, the operator assigns to `t` which is a reference (modifies it) then returns the value.

That's what an incrementation operator does: modifies & returns reference at the same time so the incremented value can be used in another operation.

Comment: For the sake of clarity 7 years later, this is what an increment operator does as long as it is a *pre*-increment operation (i.e. `++i`). Otherwise, with `i++` we return `i` first without modifying, and then modify the reference. :-)

Answer (score 8):

`t = Traficlight::yellow` writes `Traficlight::yellow` into `t`. The result of that expression is also `Traficlight::yellow`, so this:

```
return t = Traficlight::yellow;
```

is equal to:

```
t = Traficlight::yellow;
return t;
```

In the function above, reference to `t` was received as argument, so changing value of `t` is in fact relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Your function receives argument by reference:

```
Traficlight& operator++(Traficlight& t)
```

And it is a ++ operator, so semantically it must increment it's operand and then return reference to that operand. So you must do two actions:

```
// Assign new value to the t
t = Traficlight::yellow;
// Return rusult
return t;
```

This can be written in one line because assignment operator returns the assigned value.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns value to `t` variable (and in your code `t` is reference type so the change is visible outside), and then return value of `t` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `Traficlight::yellow` would be an *rvalue*, and your function returns  a reference to `t` after changing `t`'s value, which is an *lvalue*. Assignment `operator=` on its own returns a reference to its left argument.

The code is ill-formed, some old compilers consider it IFNDR.

One thing though post-increment `operator++` in expression `Trafic++` is expected to return value before incrementation and would have different signature, so this implementation is misleading  and seems to be mixed up with pre-increment operator++. It actually looks like you're using an old non-conforming compiler which allows use of built-in increment operator on an `enum` (some *ancient* Visual Studio?). In this case it's a bug and your `operator++` isn't used at all.

Changing signature to `Traficlight& operator++(Traficlight& t, int)` would make it compile, although behaviour would be non-idiomatic. `++Trafic;` also would compile by a standard compiler.

PS. Idiomatic post-increment looks something like this, no reference returned:

```
Traficlight operator++(Traficlight& t)
{
    switch (t)
    {
    case green: t = Traficlight::yellow; return Traficlight::green;
    case yellow: return t = Traficlight::red; return Traficlight::yellow;
    case red: return t = Traficlight::green; return Traficlight::red;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

`++Torch` can be used as an lvalue. `Torch++` cannot, it is supposed to return the old value of variable. It's easy to remember which signature to use - for unary operators argument goes after the operator. If argument goes before operator, it must be a binary one. Except here the second argument doesn't exist.